# Laravel Livewire with AlpineJS: Entangle a Collection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a Livewire component with the following properties...

```php
class MyClass extends Livewire\Component {

    public $dataCollection;  // instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
    public $dataArray;       // converted to an array of arrays

    /* ... blah ... */

    function getData() {
        /* ... */
        $this->dataCollection = $ordersModel->processMySearch($srch)->get(); // returns multiple lines of data, producing a Collection
        $this->dataArray = $this->dataCollection->toArray();
    }
}
```

Now, my objective is push this data to the Livewire/Blade template and entangle it with an AlpineJS variable.

```html
<div x-data="{
    myCollection: @entangle('dataCollection').defer,
    myArray:      @entangle('dataArray').defer
}">
<table>
<tbody>
    <template x-for="myRow in myCollection">
    <tr>
        <template x-for="(myData, colName) in myRow">
            <td :class="colName" x-text="myData"></td>
        </template>
    </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

It doesn't work, because it seems that the collection of models doesn't convert (or map) properly from Livewire/PHP into the Alpine `myCollection` variable.  When I run a `console.log()` debug on the variable, it tells me that it's an empty array.

[image]

However, if I loop the table the `myArray` variable (rather than the `myCollection` one):

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <template x-for="myRow in myArray">
    <tr>
    <!-- etc -->
```

Then the HTML table generates on page nicely.

The reason I would prefer to use the Collection object, is because I may want to update some of the data in the table.  If I am able to update the data in the (`@entangle`ed) Model objects and have the Models synch back to the Livewire/PHP component, then I won't need to re-generate the models in PHP, potentially saving me some database calls.

Is it possible to `@entangle` Alpine variables to PHP Collections in this way?  If so, what am I doing wrong and why isn't it working in the above example?

x

---

***Disclaimer**
The above code is a (very) simplified excerpt of a larger project that I'm working on.  It's not a direct copy/paste of the original code and as such may contain minor syntax errors.  Please treat it as pseudo code.*

Comment: there's a diff between the declared property in component and this in Alpine @entangle('dataCollectionData').defer. It's a typo?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.  I'll correct it. Thanks for pointing it out.  It doesn't change the point over the overall question.

Answer (score 0):

To use a collection of models within a Livewire component, you need to set validation rules to tell Livewire which properties are available, due to security reasons.

In your case, you should add this to the class to instruct Livewire to send specific data:

```
protected $rules = [
        'dataCollection.*.date' => 'required',
        'dataCollection.*.total' => 'required',
        ...
    ];
```

Said that, if you were not going to dynamically change rows within your component, it would be simpler to remove the entanglement and let the server side render handle it.

I mean, instead of `x-for`, using `@foreach`.